# How can perform two related database query in get_context_data i.e. use "request"?

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-class-based-views

I need to perform two database queries i.e.

```
select * from books
```

and

```
select * from chapters where book_id=id
```

On the UI i need to have a list of books (that i can get with the first query) and on click of any of the book, i want to use its id to get all the chapters(from 2nd query).
I am trying to create a class based view(template view) and having issues in how to perform these two queries in `get_context_data()` . I tried using `request.GET.get` but failed.
can anyone please help.

i want to have UI for eg.

```
Book 1
   chapter 1
   chapter 2
Book 2 
Book 3
```

Comment: The second query may benefit from being an ajax call (with a function based view or even a DetailView if need be)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways, the easiest one is:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#adding-extra-context

Assuming some Model/View names:

**models.py**

```
class Book(model.Model):
    title = CharField()

class Chapter(model.Model):
    book = ForeignKey(Book, related_name='chapters')
```

**views.py**

```
class BookDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Book

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Call the base implementation first to get a context
        context = super(BookDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # Add in a QuerySet of all the books
        context['all_books'] = Book.objects.all()
        return context
```

**bookdetails.html**

```
{{ object.title }}
{% for chapter in object.chapters %}
    {{ chapter.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: this will give me only the list of books, how am i going to get the id of the books model to query the chapters model. please see the edit(for the kind of UI that i need)

Comment: Please take a look at my updated answer. It's assuming some stuff.
A DetailView will give you context['object'] automatically, which is your Book-object. The chapters are in object.chapters (via ForeignKey + related_name)